# How to properly ssh into my remote (mac) computer from abroad?

Tags: networking, ssh, mac, vpn

I have a mac (`mac 1`) computer connected to the internet via a router from an internet proveider in country A.

I am now in country B and need to ssh from another mac (`mac 2`) into `mac 1` in country A.

I already set up `mac 1` to receive ssh connection, I tested it with both `mac 1` and `mac 2` in the same room/network in country A and ssh was working fine.

Now I am in country B and when i try to ssh from mac 1 to mac 2 I get `ssh: connect to host <myremoteIP> port 22: Network is unreachable`. This happens because of the firewall in my router in country A, correct?

After some research looks like I have 2 options:

1. port forwarding: ask my router to redirect ssh connection request on port x to the IP of my `mac 1`
2. use a vpn connection so that both `mac 1` and `mac 2` are connected to the same VPN network (in that case it should work, correct?)

---

**My questions are:**

**Q1**: is port forwarding safe or would that expose my `mac 1` to external attacks?

**Q2**: I could not find a guide on how to connect two computers to the same network via VPN, is this possible and how?would get say a CyberGhost VPN subscription solve my problem easily?

p.s. I have a person who could do some simple operations in country A on mac 1 for me.

Comment: Honestly, at consumer-level, just get a commercial remote desktop solution, forget about trying to punch holes in remote routers & tracking their ever-changing addresses [even before you hit the CGNAT brick wall]. See https://www.lifewire.com/free-remote-access-software-tools-2625161 for some ideas.

Comment: What IP are you attempting to connect to? What is the first octet of it?

Comment: @Tetsujin wow I did not know there were so many free options!
I'll try Google Remote Desktop.